# ¿Cómo obtener datos especificos de un array mediante una variable recibida por PHP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Tengo un problema al intentar imprimir los datos desde un array, lo que estoy intentando hacer es que dependiendo del value de un select, este variable se busque en el array y me haga un autollenado. Aqui le pongo un Value 0 que es el primer valor del array.

[image: Array]

Como pueden observar en la siguiente imagen, no reconoce el value debido a que el array solo me reconoce del 0 al 6 que son el numero de elementos que tiene, aquí ya ocupo el Value que me arroja el select que es 23.

[image: Array2]

Aquí mi codigo JavaScript

```
  function consult() {
                    $.ajax({
                      url: "consulta.php",
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(data) {
                        cambioOpciones(data);
                      }
                    })
                  }

                  function cambioOpciones(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (combo = 'skmx_pn1') {
                      // Obtener y almacenar el valor de skmx_pn
                      var id_cpn = document.getElementById('skmx_pn1').value;

                      console.log(id_cpn);
                      document.getElementById('customer1').value = data[id_cpn][2];
                      document.getElementById('customer_pn1').value = data[id_cpn][3];
                      document.getElementById('description1').value = data[id_cpn][4];
                    }
                  }
```

A lo que entiendo, data[id_cpn] accede a la numeración de las fillas del array, mientras que el [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7mPn.png) a la columna de esa fila , pero no se como hacer que el lugar de acceder a la numeracion del array, acceda a la columna 0 que es donde esta el dato con el que quiero trabajar`data[id_cpn][2];`

Aqui la consulta donde mando a pedir los datos con Ajax
consulta.php

```
try {
    $datos = $conn->query("SELECT id_cpn, skmx_pn, customer, customer_pn, description FROM tbl_customer_pn");
    $data = $datos->fetch_All(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print json_encode($data);

    $conn->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Aqui es donde tengo el form, que es donde se deben de introducir los datos, igual aqui esta el select que me regresa el valor del id_cpn de mis productos.
crear-in.php

```
                      for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) { ?>
                        <tr class="fila-fija">

                          <input type="hidden" style="width : 140px;" id="customer<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="customer[]" placeholder="customer" />
                          <input type="hidden" id="folio<?php echo ($i); ?>" name="folio[]" value="<?php echo $f; ?>">
                          <td>
                            <select class="fotm-control" type="text" style="width : 90px;" id="skmx_pn<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="skmx_pn[]" placeholder="SKMX PN" onchange="consult();" />
                            <option>- SKMX PN -</option>

                            <?php
                            try {
                              $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer_pn ";
                              $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
                              while ($tbl_customer_pn = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $tbl_customer_pn['id_cpn']; ?>"><?php echo $tbl_customer_pn['skmx_pn']; ?></option>
                                <!--  -->
                            <?php }
                            } catch (Exception $e) {
                              echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                            } ?>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 180px;" id="description<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="description[]" placeholder="Description" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 90px;" id="customer_pn<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="customer_pn[]" placeholder="Customer PN" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 120px;" id="shop_order<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="shop_order[]" placeholder="# Shop Order" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 70px;" id="po<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="po[]" placeholder="# P.O." /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 100px;" id="lote<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="lote[]" placeholder="Lote" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="quantity<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="location<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="location[]" placeholder="Location" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="incoming<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="incoming[]" placeholder="" readonly /></td>

                        </tr>
                      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: en un archivo `.php` debes de usar variables `$_POST['id_html']` para detectarlas, javascript es un lenguaje que modifica la pagina sin procesarla, con ajax solo preparas los archivos para mandarlos al servidor. Pero el que lo opera es PHP

Comment: Creo comprender lo que me dices, ya tengo un archivo php que me hace la consulta a la base de datos y el array que se muestra es la consulta retornada por JSON. Teniendolas ya de regreso en JS, lo que quiero es acceder a ellas, no con su indice que es del 0 al 6(que son las filas que tiene al array), sino con la numeracion que tiene la fila, que son 22,23,27,28,30,etc. Mas no se si sea posible. Perdon si no me explique bien y si no comprendi tu respuesta.

Comment: puedes porfavor publicar todo el codigo, es dificil ayudarte si no sabemos como funciona

Comment: @EgonStetmann. Ya actualice la pregunta, una disculpa, no creí que fuera necesario meter todo el codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas [buscar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) en el arreglo el elemento que coincida con `id_cpn` y asignarlo a una variable:

```
function cambioOpciones(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (combo = 'skmx_pn1') {
        // Obtener y almacenar el valor de skmx_pn
        let id_cpn = document.getElementById('skmx_pn1').value;
        console.log(id_cpn);

        // Buscar elemento en arreglo de datos
        let item = data.find(el => el[1] == id_cpn);

        // Verificar que se encontró el elemento
        if(typeof item == 'undefined' || !item) {
            console.log(`No se encontró ${id_cpn}`);
            return;
        }

        // item contiene el arreglo del elemento encontrado
        document.getElementById('customer1').value = item[2];
        document.getElementById('customer_pn1').value = item[3];
        document.getElementById('description1').value = item[4];
    }
}
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta, me sirvio a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Si id_cpn es igual 23 no puedes acceder a data [id_cpn], es decir data[23][2] no existe.

El campo select debe tener la clave del array (key) del 0 a 6 y actualmente contiene la columna 0 de cada fila, que parece ser la id del la base de datos.

Comment: Comprendo lo que me dices, asigne el valor 0 para explicar que solo puedo acceder al array mediante el indice de filas del array, lo que queria saber es si es posible acceder al array con un dato que no sea el indice, por ejemplo, en la consulta tengo el num 23, quiero que al seleccionar en el select me tome el valor 23 y lo busque en el array por el 23 y no por su indice, que me marcaria error debido a que solo tiene filas del 0 al 6. Perdon si no me logro explicar bien.

Comment: Entiendo. Aunque JavaScript tiene métodos como incluye() o indexOf() que podrían ayudarte... Creo que en cualquier caso tienes que recorrer el array en bucle buscando la coincidencia. Quizá puedes ordenar el array de otra forma desde backend o recorrer el array desde el frontend para montar el selector a tu necesidad. Siento no poder haber sido de más ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por intentar ayudarme, te lo agradezco.